# php mysql default value of TEXT type on database

Tags: php, mysql

I am on a school poject doing a simple forum PHP & MySQL based.
i just want to ask if i can set a default value like **no_avatar.jpg** on my database if the user dint uploaded a image file?

Comment: yeh since i use input on form, ive tried adding a value="no_avatar.jpg" but no luck it returns empty string on my database table

     <input name="avatar" type="file" id="avatar" value="no_avatar.jpg" accept="image/*"/>

Comment: You said a default value in DB, that's not DB code. You need to show your SQL, not HTML form code. You can always set a default value in your table's column also. Plus, there's a reason why it's doing that.

Comment: You will be better served by leaving the db table blank, and detecting its absence in PHP and insert the default value in your application code.  That way when you decide to replace no_avatar.jpg with blank.jpg you only (hopefully) change one value.

Comment: im sorry i cant upload image yet, but my datatype for avatar field is TEXT, and i cannot assign a default value as it says on the mysql #1101 - BLOB/TEXT column 'avatar' can't have a default value

Answer (score 0):

Yes Ron, you are right. BLOB/TEXT datatype can not have default value. 
**[BLOB and TEXT columns cannot have DEFAULT values.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/blob.html)**

Instead you should insert default value when inserting data into table.

Just check if user entered something, if not, just use default image name.

Comment: thank you for the hint, and yes ive tried it already, <input name="avatar" type="file" id="avatar" value="no_avatar.jpg" accept="image/*"/> but it doesn't send/insert the no_avatar.jpg into my table

Comment: You need to post your code so that I can check. Post `HTML`, `PHP` & `Mysql Table Structure` code.